# comparing responses in dynamic quiz with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

hi im totally noob at jquery im trying to leanr so i decided to make a dynamic quiz in order to improve my skills i've been doing it one step at a time an then try to wrap it all togheter. I got stuck in the way of how to check wich one of my checkbox is checked to compare if its the correct answer and then update the question and the answers. here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>Dynamic Quiz</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prefixfree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/codigo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>This is my Dynamic Quiz</h1>
        <h2>Using html5 / css / javascript</h2>
    </hgruop>
</header>

<section id='description'>
    <p>This quiz is compossed by 10 questions, you have to answer at least 7
       from 10 to pass the exam.</p>
    <h2>Lets start!</h2>
</section>

<div id='questions-number'>
    <p>Question <span id='current-question'>1</span> of <span>10</span> </p>
</div>

<section id='questions'>
    <p id='question'></p>

    <ul>
        <li><input type='checkbox' id='checkAnswer0'/><label id='answer0'>answer0</label></li>
        <li><input type='checkbox' id='checkAnswer1'/><label id='answer1'>answer1</label></li>
        <li><input type='checkbox' id='checkAnswer2'/><label id='answer2'>answer2</label></li>
        <li><input type='checkbox' id='checkAnswer3'/><label id='answer3'>answer3</label></li>
    </ul>
</section>

<div id='next'>
    next
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is what i got in jquery so far :)

```
$(document).on('ready', ready);
function ready(){
var allQuestions =
[
    {
        question1: "Whats my real name?",
        choices1: ["Jhonnatan", "Alberto", "Tatan","Jaime"],
        answer1: 0
    },

    {
        question2: "Who is Colombia's president?",
        choices2: ["Alvaro Uribe", "Andres Pastrana", "Juan Manuel Santos","Tatan"],
        answer2: 2
    },

    {
        question3: "My favorite super heroe?",
        choices3: ["Batman", "Flash", "Tatan","Javascript"],
        answer3: 3
    },

    {
        question4: "Wich sports do i practice?",
        choices4: ["Climbing", "Swimming", "Programming","Running"],
        answer4: 0
    },

    {
        question5: "Whats my dad's name?",
        choices5: ["Alberto", "Jorge", "Javier","Jose"],
        answer5: 1
    },

    {
        question6: "Whats my favorite color?",
        choices6: ["Red", "Purple", "Blue","All"],
        answer6: 2
    },

    {
        question7: "My favorite alcoholic drink",
        choices7: ["Vodka", "Aguardiente", "Rum","Tekila"],
        answer7: 3
    },

    {
        question8: "Whats my favorite kind of music?",
        choices8: ["Hardcore", "Reggaeton", "Salsa","Programming"],
        answer8: 0
    },

    {
        question9: "How many qestions has this quiz??",
        choices9: ["20", "8", "10","12"],
        answer9: 2
    },

    {
        question10: "My favorite programming lenguage?",
        choices10: ["Ruby", "Arduino", "Python","Javascript"],
        answer10: 3
    }
];
var question = $('#question');
var choice1 = $('#answer0');
var choice2 = $('#answer1');
var choice3 = $('#answer2');
var choice4 = $('#answer3');

question.text(allQuestions[0].question1);
choice1.text(allQuestions[0].choices1[0]);
choice2.text(allQuestions[0].choices1[1]);
choice3.text(allQuestions[0].choices1[2]);
choice4.text(allQuestions[0].choices1[3]);
console.log('funcionando!');

var next = $('#next');
next.on('click', changeQuestion);   
function changeQuestion(){
    var checked = $('#checkAnswer0');
    if($checked.prop('checked')){
        console.log('correcto')else{
            console.log('no es correctp'); 
        }
    }
}
}
```

i will appreciate your help if you help me with this! :)

Comment: why don't you add the value attribute to each one of your checkboxes and compare against that - it would seem easier.  Also it would seem radio buttons would be more appropriate for this if it's multiple choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/AYU5Y/) seems to do what you're trying to accomplish.  I've tried to modify as little of your code as possible, so hopefully this makes sense!

For example, it's much easier to iterate through an object/array when the keys are consistent.

```
{
    question: "Whats my real name?",
    choices: ["Jhonnatan", "Alberto", "Tatan","Jaime"],
    answer: 0
},

... instead of ...

{
    question1: "Whats my real name?",
    choices1: ["Jhonnatan", "Alberto", "Tatan","Jaime"],
    answer1: 0
},
```

Comment: i just saw your example im made it something similar...ill study your code to understand it better and improve mine...ty very much

Answer (score 1):

Glad you're trying to learn. There's a lot of cleanup and efficiency things you can practice after but you can find the checked element several ways, like `$(elem).is(':checked')` or `$(':checked')` to find all.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i made it :) im verry happy i did it, i just saw @cmallard example and it seems i still need to improve some things, also seems that im in the correct way...if yo guys have any suggestions i would like to see them! :)

```
$(document).on('ready', ready);
function ready(){
var allQuestions =
[
    {
        question: "Whats my real name?",
        choices: ["Jhonnatan", "Alberto", "Tatan","Jaime"],
        answer: 0
    },

    {
        question: "Who is Colombia's president?",
        choices: ["Alvaro Uribe", "Andres Pastrana", "Juan Manuel Santos","Tatan"],
        answer: 2
    },

    {
        question: "My favorite super heroe?",
        choices: ["Batman", "Flash", "Tatan","Javascript"],
        answer: 3
    },

    {
        question: "Wich sports do i practice?",
        choices: ["Climbing", "Swimming", "Programming","Running"],
        answer: 0
    },

    {
        question: "Whats my dad's name?",
        choices: ["Alberto", "Jorge", "Javier","Jose"],
        answer: 1
    },

    {
        question: "Whats my favorite color?",
        choices: ["Red", "Purple", "Blue","All"],
        answer: 2
    },

    {
        question: "My favorite alcoholic drink",
        choices: ["Vodka", "Aguardiente", "Rum","Tekila"],
        answer: 3
    },

    {
        question: "Whats my favorite kind of music?",
        choices: ["Hardcore", "Reggaeton", "Salsa","Programming"],
        answer: 0
    },

    {
        question: "How many qestions has this quiz??",
        choices: ["20", "8", "10","12"],
        answer: 2
    },

    {
        question: "My favorite programming lenguage?",
        choices: ["Ruby", "Arduino", "Python","Javascript"],
        answer: 3
    }
];

var number=0;
var question = $('#question');
var choice1 = $('#answer0');
var choice2 = $('#answer1');
var choice3 = $('#answer2');
var choice4 = $('#answer3');
var next = $('#next');
var currentQuestion = $('#current-question');

next.on('click', changeQuestion);
addQuestionAndAnswers();    



function addQuestionAndAnswers() {
    currentQuestion.text(number + 1);
    question.text(allQuestions[number].question);
    choice1.text(allQuestions[number].choices[0]);
    choice2.text(allQuestions[number].choices[1]);
    choice3.text(allQuestions[number].choices[2]);
    choice4.text(allQuestions[number].choices[3]);
    console.log('funcionando!');
}


function changeQuestion(){
    if(number!=9){
        if($("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").val() ==
 allQuestions[number].answer){
            number = number +1;
            addQuestionAndAnswers();
        } else{
            console.log('respuesta errada');
        }
    } else {
        displayResult();
    }


    function displayResult(){
        currentQuestion.text('10');
        $('#myForm').css('display', 'none');
        $('#question').css('display', 'none');
        $('#next').css('display', 'none');
        $('#score').css('display', 'inline-block')
        $('#score').text('Your score is: ' + (number + 1) + 'pts');


    }
}
}
```